# Drag and Drop in GUI

Tags: oop, user-interface, function, matlab, cursor-position

Is it possible to create an object in a GUI whose position I can define by the cursor position (drag when clicked) by setting its 'Position' property to whatever the cursor position is? What function should I be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SELECTMOVERESIZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/selectmoveresize.html) function to turn on moving and resizing for your GUI object. Then you can just click and drag the object with the mouse. It's as simple as this:

```
set(hObject,'ButtonDownFcn','selectmoveresize');
```

What's not so simple is if your GUI object is a [uicontrol object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol.html), in which case you will have to disable the object by setting the [`'Enable'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#Enable) to `'off'` or `'inactive'` in order to have the [`'ButtonDownFcn'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#ButtonDownFcn) function execute instead of the [`'Callback'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#Callback) function. This is true even if you haven't defined a callback for the object.

You will also probably need to add a means to your GUI to turn the moving and resizing of the object on and off, perhaps an extra button or a menu item you can select. To show how you could do this with a push button, here's a simple example that creates a figure with an editable text box and a push button that turns on and off the ability to move and resize the editable text box:

```
function GUI_example

  hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 200 200],...  %# Create a figure
                   'MenuBar','none',...
                   'ToolBar','none');
  hEdit = uicontrol('Style','edit',...               %# Create a multi-line
                    'Parent',hFigure,...             %#   editable text box
                    'Position',[10 30 180 160],...
                    'Max',2,...
                    'String',{'(type here)'});
  hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...       %# Create a push button
                      'Parent',hFigure,...
                      'Position',[50 5 100 20],...
                      'String','Turn moving on',...
                      'Callback',@button_callback);

  function button_callback(hSource,eventData)        %# Nested button callback

    if strcmp(get(hSource,'String'),'Turn moving on')
      set(hSource,'String','Turn moving off');          %# Change button text
      set(hEdit,'Enable','inactive',...                 %# Disable the callback
                'ButtonDownFcn','selectmoveresize',...  %# Turn on moving, etc.
                'Selected','on');                       %# Display as selected
    else
      set(hSource,'String','Turn moving on');           %# Change button text
      set(hEdit,'Enable','on',...                       %# Re-enable the callback
                'ButtonDownFcn','',...                  %# Turn off moving, etc.
                'Selected','off');                      %# Display as unselected
    end

  end

end
```

**Note:** although the documentation lists the [`'Selected'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#Selected) as read-only, I was able to modify it without a problem. It must be a typo in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Could you tell me where the function obtains its input arguments from?

Comment: @Adam: Which function? SELECTMOVERESIZE doesn't take any arguments as input.

Comment: The button_callback function taking in hSource and eventData.

Comment: @Adam: When you declare the callback of an object as a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html), it will automatically be passed two arguments by default: the handle of the object issuing the callback and event data it optionally provides. Check [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f16-999606.html#f16-1001315) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an invisible axes in your GUI, and plot whatever objects you want in there. Then, you can use [DRAGGABLE](http://www.mathworks.jp/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable) from the File Exchange to allow for dragging objects all over the place.